# mocking when multiple RestTemplate

Tags: spring-boot, junit, mockito

I have multiple resttempletes in configured for my springboot project.
I am unable to mock individual resttemplate for my test case.

I tried with same name mock, the mocking is not happening.

Here is my configuration

```java
@Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplateA(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .setConnectTimeout(2000)
                .setReadTimeout(5000)
                .basicAuthorization(aUsername, aPassword)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplateB(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .setConnectTimeout(20000)
                .setReadTimeout(50000)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplateC(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder
                .setConnectTimeout(20000)
                .basicAuthorization(bUsername, bPassword)
                .setReadTimeout(50000)
                .build();
    }
```

Actual call for resttemplate, which works fine and we need to write test case is:

```java
ResponseEntity<AClass> responseEntity = restTemplateB.exchange(uriBuilder.toUriString(),
                    HttpMethod.GET, entity, AClass.class);
```

Mockito.when is not working and actual call to the url happens and connection exception occurs.

```java
@Mock
private RestTemplate restTemplateB;

@Test
public void test_B() throws Exception {
        AClass response = gson.fromJson(
                FileUtils.readFileToString(ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:sample/AJson.json"),
                        Charset.forName("utf-8")),
                AClass.class);
        ResponseEntity<AClass> responseEntity = new ResponseEntity<>(response,
                HttpStatus.ACCEPTED);
        Mockito.when(restTemplateB.exchange(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any(HttpMethod.class),
                Mockito.any(HttpEntity.class),
                Mockito.<ParameterizedTypeReference<AClass>>any()))
                .thenReturn(responseEntity);
        service.testMethod("abc");
        assertNotNull(responseEntity.getBody());
    }
```

Exception:

```java
org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://abc/": Connect to abc:80 [abc/10.25.100.11] failed: Connection refused: connect; nested exception is org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to abc:80 [abc/101.252.110.100] failed: Connection refused: connect
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this a unit or an integration test?

If this is a unit test, the name of the bean does not matter, just inject the mocked bean into the class you are trying to test when creating the underTest (service) instance.

If this is an integration test, do not use `@Mock`, use `@MockBean` to inject the mocked bean into the application context (so that it can override the beans in your context).
`MockBean` also has a `name` parameter that can be used to override a specific named bean.